# Perl sort numbers naturally

Tags: perl, sorting

I need to sort numbers and I am not able to get it to work the way I want.

Example input:

```
15.12
16.1
15.2
15.1
```

Expected output:

```
15.1
15.2
15.12
16.1
```

I tried normal sort and also `Sort::Naturally` for this. Neither works giving me the expected output.

I am also aware I can do something like the following to sort it the way I want.

```
my @sorted =
map sprintf('%vd', $_),
sort
map join('', map chr, split /\./),
@data;
```

I am wondering if there are some pre existent modules that I can use though.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to sort version numbers, where each component is sorted independently. Sort::Naturally won't work because it ignores non-alphanumeric characters, but there are several other modules that can do this.

[Sort::Versions](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Versions) splits its input on periods or hyphens and sorts each group either alphabetically or numerically, depending on whether non-digit characters are present:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

use Sort::Versions;

my @versions = (
    15.12,
    16.1,
    15.2,
    15.1
);

say for sort { versioncmp($a, $b) } @versions;
```

Output:

```
15.1
15.2
15.12
16.1
```

Sort::Versions expects input to match certain common version string formats; if you need to sort different formats than what you've shown, check the rules in the documentation to make sure it will work for you.

---

[Sort::Key::Natural](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Natural) is more flexible because it splits on all word boundaries, not just periods and hyphens, but in this case it works the same:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

use Sort::Key::Natural qw(natsort);

my @versions = (
    15.12,
    16.1,
    15.2,
    15.1
);

say for natsort @versions;
```

(Output is the same as for Sort::Versions)

Sort::Key::Natural has some nice additional features, like the ability to sort in place and to customize the sort order. It was also significantly faster than Sort::Versions in my benchmarks, although that will only matter if you're sorting large arrays.

Comment: They look like standard floating-point numbers to me. It's a big leap to assume that they're version strings

Comment: @Borodin Look at the expected output. They want to sort 15.2 before 15.12.

Comment: Yes, they are version numbers. And thank you. Your solution just works.

Answer (score 6):

If I understood it right, you want to sort the numbers by integer value first and then consider the decimal part as an integer itself, so `.12` is greater than `.2` like in your example (12 > 2).

I think the most self explanatory way is to use a custom sort, after splitting them as you said:

```
@sorted = sort {
    my ($a1, $a2) = split /\./, $a;
    my ($b1, $b2) = split /\./, $b;
    $a1 <=> $b1 or $a2 <=> $b2
} @numbers;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare (`<=>`) the numbers with the special `$a` and `$b` variables. Note that you can do the same with strings by replacing `<=>` with `cmp`.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @nums = qw(15.1 16.1 15.12);

@nums = sort {$a <=> $b} @nums;

print "$_\n" for @nums;

__END__
15.1
15.12
16.1
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question and drops value "15.2" which would show up as not matching the need in the question.

Comment: @Richlv Nice catch! I have no idea how I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the answer provided by @stevieb, value "15.2" was not dropped: it was missing in the original array. Operators `<=>` and `cmp` are not exchangeable, though. They are used to compare numbers and strings, respectively.